# How to submit the score in HUAWEI Unity Game service in Official plugin?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

how to submit the scores for the leaderboard in Game service in Unity Platform.

While using the IGetLeaderboardsListener method the score always showing as 1. So in that case, how to submit the score there.

Answer (score 0):

if  you  want  to submit the score for leaderboard in unity，you can use：

HuaweiGameService.SubmitScore(string leaderboardId, int score)

unity document link:

https://docs.unity.cn/cn/Packages-cn/com.unity.huaweiservice@1.3/manual/gameservices.html

1. HuaweiGameService.SubmitScore(string leaderboardId, int score, string scoreTag)
   Submit a score to a leaderboard for the currently signed-in player.
2. HuaweiGameService.AsyncSubmitScore(string leaderboardId, int score, string scoreTag, ISubmitScoreListener listener)
   Submit a score to a leaderboard for the currently signed-in player, this method gets the callback asynchronously.